ChatGPT - "Something went wrong" every reply
Scenario:
ChatGPT keeps giving me the same response over and over "Something went wrong. If this issue persists please contact us through our help center at help.openai.com." Scouring the web leads to "disable vpn" "clear cache". I've tried multiple networks, multiple devices, multiple browser to no avail.
Question:
How do I get past this?

I eventually solved this issue by selecting the "Switch Model" button (below the last chatgpt output) and switched to "More Models > GPT-4 [Legacy]" then my question worked. As of late I'm having to do this for every question but at least it works. Make note that some of the other models, such as "o1 Preview" are pretty interesting and may tackle your question better than 4o.
the "switch model" button:

